# Safari-style tabs Cocoa control?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I'm referring to the Safari 8's tabbar control (which looks almost exactly the same with Xcode 6's tabbar + the horizontal scrolling, if I'm not mistaken)

[image: tabbar safari]

Is it available somewhere? How do I proceed?

---

**P.S.:** If the answer is something along the lines of *"It's a custom control. But you can do it very easily by subclassing... everything there is to subclass"*, I'm prepared for it! lol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a custom control: ScrollableTabBarView. You can inspect it using [F-Script](http://pmougin.wordpress.com/2009/08/29/f-script-anywhere-on-snowy/)

The closest visual match is the Yosemite style of [MMTabBarView](https://github.com/ajin/MMTabBarView). This control however does not implement scrolling.

Also check out [LITabControl](https://github.com/monyschuk/LITabControl) and [KPCTabsControl](https://github.com/onekiloparsec/KPCTabsControl)

Comment: LITabControl is a great suggestion I believe. And it supports scrolling too - how is it possible that I've never spotted it?! Thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: Thanks for link on LITabControl and MMTabBarView

Comment: LITabControl have some bugs when using with storyboard. So i recommend to use MMTabBarView. Last one is a great solution, but sadly have some visual bugs with Yosemite-style-tabs (like in Safari in Yosemite). But some people already solved it: check out this fork https://github.com/ajin/MMTabBarView and this fork https://github.com/dparnell/MMTabBarView I almost created my fork for it but found out this repositories.

Answer (score 2):

It is just a Segmented / Tab bar with customized Radio buttons with added NSButton(this is for closing the tab).

You could check this using Accessibility Inspector.

And there is no straightforward control to achieve this, as you mentioned in P.S., you should go with customizing the controls.

Comment: Well, I didn't even think of a segmented control! Let's see what I can do... Thanks a lot for your help! :-)